# child_process spawn Race condition possibility in nodejs

Tags: node.js, race-condition, fs

I'm starting to learn and use node and I like it but I'm not really sure how certain features work. Maybe you can help me resolve one such issue:

I want to spawn local scripts and programs from my node server upon rest commands. looking at the fs library I saw the example below of how to spawn a child process and add some pipes/event handlers on it.

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    ps    = spawn('ps', ['ax']),
    grep  = spawn('grep', ['ssh']);

ps.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  grep.stdin.write(data);
});

ps.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('ps stderr: ' + data);
});

ps.on('close', function (code) {
  if (code !== 0) {
    console.log('ps process exited with code ' + code);
  }
  grep.stdin.end();
});

grep.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('' + data);
});

grep.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('grep stderr: ' + data);
});

grep.on('close', function (code) {
  if (code !== 0) {
    console.log('grep process exited with code ' + code);
  }
});
```

What's weird to me is that I don't understand how I can be guaranteed that the event handler code will be registered before the program starts to run. It's not like there's a 'resume' function that you run to start up the child. Isn't this a race condition? Granted the condition would be minisculy small and would almost never hit because its such a short snipping of code afterward but still, if it is I'd rather not code it this way out of good habits.

So:
1) if it's not a race condition why?
2) if it is a race condition how could I write it the right way?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a race condition. Node.js is single threaded and handles events on a first come first serve basis. New events are put at the end of the event loop. Node will execute your code in a synchronous manner, part of which will involve setting up event emitters. When these event emitters emit events, they will be put to the end of the queue, and will not be handled until Node finishes executing whatever piece of code its currently working on, which happens to be the same code that registers the listener. Therefore, the listener will always be registered before the event is handled.

Comment: Thanks Yuri, that makes sense for the situation I asked where spawn is made from the main server code.  Just to get more clarification, if I spawned a child which in turn spawned children, would your logic still hold?

Comment: No problem. I don't see why it wouldn't.

Comment: I don't understand this. Node can only control its own threading model, it has no control over child processes it spawns. When I step through some code that `spawn`s a child process and inspect the value `spawn` returns, it already has a process ID as soon as I reach the next statement, which means the process is running before any of my handlers have been registered (at least on Windows). This means you are wrong.

Comment: Yes, your child process is certainly running, and is possibly emitting events, but those events aren't being processed yet. Using OP's example, only after finishing executing the current context (in which the child process is spawned and event handlers are setup) would Node begin handling the events emitted by the child process.

Answer (score 2):

Given the slight conflict and ambiguity in the accepted answer's comments, the sample and output below tells me two things:

1. The child process (referring to the node object returned by `spawn`) emits no events even though the real underlying process is live / executing.
2. The pipes for the IPC are setup before the child process is executed.

Both are obvious. The conflict is w.r.t. interpretation of the OP's question:-

Actually 'yes', this is the epitome of a data race condition if one needs to consider the real child process's side effects. But 'no', there's no data race as far as IPC pipe plumbing is concerned. The data is written to a buffer and retrieved as a (bigger) blob as and when (as already well described) the context completes allowing the event loop to continue.

The first data event seen below pushes not 1 but 5 chunks written to stdout by the child process whilst we were blocking.. thus nothing is lost.

sample:

```
let t = () => (new Date()).toTimeString().split(' ')[0]
let p = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  console.log(`[${t()}|info] spawning`);

  let cp = spawn('bash', ['-c', 'for x in `seq 1 1 10`; do printf "$x\n"; sleep 1; done']);
  let resolved = false;

  if (cp === undefined)
    reject();

  cp.on('error', (err) => {
    console.log(`error: ${err}`);
    reject(err);
  });

  cp.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    if (!resolved) {
      console.log(`[${t()}|info] spawn succeeded`);
      resolved = true;
      resolve();
    }
    process.stdout.write(`[${t()}|data] ${data}`);
  });

  let ts = parseInt(Date.now() / 1000);
  while (parseInt(Date.now() / 1000) - ts < 5) {
    // waste some cycles in the current context
    ts--; ts++;
  }

  console.log(`[${t()}|info] synchronous time wasted`);
});
Promise.resolve(p);
```

output:

```
[18:54:18|info] spawning
[18:54:23|info] synchronous time wasted
[18:54:23|info] spawn succeeded
[18:54:23|data] 1
2
3
4
5
[18:54:23|data] 6
[18:54:24|data] 7
[18:54:25|data] 8
[18:54:26|data] 9
[18:54:27|data] 10
```

Comment: This would be more persuasive if you moved your synchronous time wasting up to _before_ the `.on(...)` calls that attach the stdout and stderr handlers, to demonstrate that even if there's been no handler attached yet when the child process is outputting data, that data will still get buffered and ultimately passed to the `on('data', ...)` handler.

Comment: Interestingly and to my surprise, I notice that this works even if you waste time _asynchronously_, by only adding the `'data'` handlers from within a `setTimeout` callback.